# Escaping quotes in Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net

I've an object:

```
public class Test 
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to serialize it to json in a view, so in my cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myJson = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(Model.MyTest))');
</script>
```

It works, until `Prop1` contains quotes, because it gets rendered as:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse('{"Prop1":"\"Quoted text\""}');
```

Unfortunately, such a line throws parse error.
I know that it should be:

```
 var myJson = JSON.parse('{"Prop1":"\\"Quoted text\\""}');
```

How can I configure Newtonsoft to serialize it in a proper way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not parse the string for a second time, since already serialized it as JSON, you can directly use it in Javascript (the JS in JSON).

```
var myJson = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(Model.MyTest));
```

Will output:

```
var myJson = {"Prop1":"\"Quoted text\""};
```

And, [because you always need a JSFiddle to prove it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/jvgo8bbf/1/)

Comment: Nice, works! The only drawback is that intellisense gets confused and marks line as invalid.

Comment: True. That is a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get C# object into Javascript:

```
var objJSON = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject).Replace(@"\""",@"\\""").Replace("'","\\'"))';
var obj = JSON.parse(objJSON);
```